# Queuing Theory: Computing Delay Probability M/M/C

Tags: probability, queueing-theory, poisson-distribution

[image]

The delay probability is :

[image]

So let's assume that :

```
λ = 2/3;
μ = 1/3;
c = 3;
```

How do they arrive by having a queuing delay :

**Πw = 0.444  ?**

I don't know if I am computing "*p*" and "*Πw*" correctly because i never seem to get as close to 0.444.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $\rho=\dfrac23$ and $\dfrac{(c\rho)^c}{c!}=\dfrac43$ so your result is $$\Pi_W=\frac{\dfrac43}{\left(1-\dfrac23\right)\left(1+2+2\right)+ \dfrac43}=\frac49\approx 0.444.$$